# Unable to type some special characters in vi on a debian

Tags: debian, vi, locale

on a machine I have access to, when I type "€" in vi, "~B� " is displayed instead, and when I type "£", "£ "
What can cause this strange behavior, how can I fix it?
Typing it in the console gives even less results.

`locale` output :

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Inside vim (I explicitely tried using vim with an 'm'):

```
:set enc
encoding=latin1
```

This looks very wrong...

Typing `:set encoding=utf-8` solves the problem, but how can I make my system use utf-8 everywhere? The problem I'm trying to solve is the fact that a fixture file for my database seems to be interpreted as `latin1` by php...

Comment: You should fix your locales. IIRC `dpkg-reconfigure locales` should do it.

Comment: @enzotib : I'll try to have the admin do this, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As enzotib said, you need to reconfigure your locales. Run `DEBCONF_PRIORITY=low sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

- Make sure that you enable `en_US.UTF-8` in the *first* question.
- Make sure that you set `en_US.UTF-8` as the **default locale** in the *second* question.

Comment: This will be tried as soon as I can get someone with root privileges to do it.

Comment: Before I connected through ssh, my LC_CTYPE variable was set to fr_FR.UTF-8 . I think this must somehow act on the default locale

Answer (score 1):

If your `vi` is `vim`, then you must take care of your locales and the settings of enconding inside vim:

First question: Which locale do you use?

```
echo $LC_ALL
```

My shell prints `de_DE.utf8`

Second Question: Is it the same locale used in vim? (Inside vim session)

```
:set enc
```

My vim prints `encoding=utf-8`

HTH

Comment: I tried what you said and more and updated my answer. locale outputs two errors. +1